# Automatically maintain a copy of a Jupyter notebook as plain Python code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

**tl;dr**

Is there any feature, extension, add-on, or custom function I could use that would extend the autosave functionality in Jupyter to automatically maintain a plain text (.py) copy of the code alongside the notebook (.ipynb) file?

**Additional details**

I don't particularly like using Jupyter as an IDE, especially for code that will some day be used in production, but a lot of my teammates do. The issue is that we currently don't have any way to automate code saved as a .ipynb file. We also don't have good version control practices in place and I find myself constantly having to remind people to update the "production" copy of the code after they've finished making some changes to the notebook. I'm hoping there might be a way to address this.

Comment: I see you want to automatically convert.  What about using commandline and then write your own schedule script ?  https://www.algorist.co.uk/post/how-to-convert-jupyter-notebooks-to-python-script/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the answer in the [Jupyter Notebook documentation](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/savehooks.html)

> **File save hooks**
>
> You can configure functions that are run whenever a
> file is saved. There are two hooks available:
>
> ContentsManager.pre_save_hook runs on the API path and model with
> content. This can be used for things like stripping output that people
> don’t like adding to VCS noise.
>
> FileContentsManager.post_save_hook runs on the filesystem path and
> model without content. This could be used to commit changes after
> every save, for instance.
>
> They are both called with keyword arguments:

```
> pre_save_hook(model=model, path=path, contents_manager=cm)
> post_save_hook(model=model, os_path=os_path, contents_manager=cm)
```

First, create the jupyter_notebook_config.py file under [user directory]/.jupyter if it doesn't already exist. You can generate a template automatically with the command

`$ jupyter notebook --generate-config`

Next, add the code below:

```
import io
import os
from notebook.utils import to_api_path

_script_exporter = None

def script_post_save(model, os_path, contents_manager, **kwargs):
    """convert notebooks to Python script after save with nbconvert

    replaces `jupyter notebook --script`
    """
    from nbconvert.exporters.script import ScriptExporter

    if model['type'] != 'notebook':
        return

    global _script_exporter

    if _script_exporter is None:
        _script_exporter = ScriptExporter(parent=contents_manager)

    log = contents_manager.log

    base, ext = os.path.splitext(os_path)
    script, resources = _script_exporter.from_filename(os_path)
    script_fname = base + resources.get('output_extension', '.txt')
    log.info("Saving script /%s", to_api_path(script_fname, contents_manager.root_dir))

    with io.open(script_fname, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(script)

c.FileContentsManager.post_save_hook = script_post_save
```

© Copyright 2015, Jupyter Team, https://jupyter.org. Revision 03bc4e9e.

Answer (score 1):

[Jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) is a JupyterLab extensions that does exactly that. After pairing a notebook with a text file it will automatically keep a plain-text copy of a notebook and synchronize the changes; it can also work the other way round, synchronising a text file with a notebook:

[image]

You can try it out on a binder from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/krassowski/c8921d090fec969b00bd9b1e6f01d5bf).

The documentation of [paired notebooks](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/paired-notebooks.html) explains this feature in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Jupytext keeps two versions and updates the last not worked on. Had the same issue.

Answer (score -3):

You may try to uninstall [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) and Jupyter. Then install again. It might work.

Comment: I'm not following. Are you saying that autosaving the code as plain text is supposed to be a default feature but there might be something wrong with my installation?